# What am i doing wrong with my css that hover will not work?

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello so I have used css `hover`, `transform` and `transition` before. but it's always been as simple as `.cart:hover{do stuff}`, for some reason I'm trying to change a `h1` when it's hovered but cannot get it to work.

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40%;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  text-shadow: 8px 0 #DA0463;
}

.header:hover+h1 {
  cursor: grab;
}
```

header component

```
<div className='header'>

        <div>
            <h1> words,</h1>
            <h2>more words.</h2>
        </div>
    

    </div>
```

No variation of `.header:hover` seems to work, I even put the specific `h1` in its own `div` and tried to select it that way and still nothing, any help would be appreciated as I've already checked the other SO questions.

edit: figured it out, was editing the css in the section for mobile view.

Comment: You would need to share your markup to be certain, but the selector `.header h1` suggests you are targeting an `h1` inside `.header`, where as the selector `.header:hover+h1` suggests you are trying to target an `h1` **next to** a hovered `.header`.

Comment: You should include your HTML and use the code snippet feature to create a reproducible example. If you're trying to create an effect when hovering over the `h1`, then you probably want to put the hover on that element, like `.header h1:hover`

Comment: Ive edited it to include the component. i have also tried .header h1:hover to no avail.

Comment: If I take your above code, change `className` to `class` (as it would be rendered outside of react` and change the rule to `.header:hover h1` it works just fine.

Comment: changed it to class and changed the rule still nothing, cursor doesnt change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.header h1:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Hover me</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use

```css
.header h1:hover
```

or

```css
.header:hover, h1:hover
```

or try using an id

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn
{
  background-color:grey;
}
.btn:hover
{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click me
```